# Prove or disprove continuity of two maps

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

Yet another time I need help to prove continuity of a certain map and don't know how to do it:

> Look at the vector space
>   $$C_b^1(\mathbb R; \mathbb C) := \{f \in C^1(\mathbb R;\mathbb C):||f||_{\infty} < \infty, ||f'||_{\infty} < \infty\}.$$
>   On this space, we define the norms $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_2$ by setting
>   $$||f||_1 := ||f||_{\infty}, \quad||f||_2 := ||f||_{\infty} + ||f'||_{\infty}\qquad\forall f \in C_b^1( \mathbb R; \mathbb C).$$
>   For $i \in \{1,2\}$, prove whether the maps
>   $$d_i:(C_b^1( \mathbb R; \mathbb C),||\cdot||_i) \to (\mathbb R, |\cdot|); \quad d(f) := f'(0)$$
>   are continuous or not.

Comment: It should be clear that $d_1$ is not continuous. You can easily construct continuous functions $f_n$ such that $f_n \to 0$ in sup-norm but $f_n'(0) = 1$ for all $n$. For example you can take $f_n$ to be $0$ left from $-1/n$. Then connect $(-1/n,0)$ and $(1/n,2/n)$ by a linear piece and right from $1/n$ you take $2/n$ as function value. In the points where it is not differentiable you can also assume it to be smooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $d_1$ you can refer to the comment, and even try to find a counter-example by reading the proof for $d_2$ and see where the proof can't be applied for $d_1$ and find a counter-example from here.

For the norm $||.||_2$, you can show the continuity by noticing that :

$$|d_2(f)-d_2(g)|=|f'(0)-g'(0)|\le ||f'-g'||_{\infty} \le ||f'-g'||_{\infty} + ||f-g||_{\infty}=||f-g||_2$$

So $\forall \epsilon >0$ if $||f-g||_2 \le \epsilon$, then $|d_2(f)-d_2(g)|\le \epsilon$, so $d_2$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

For $d_1$ consider $f_n(x) = [\sin(nx)]/n, n =1,2,\dots $ Then $f_n \to 0$ in the $1$ norm, but $d_1(f_n) = 1$ for all $n.$